# Can a group of Thread (ThreadGroup) be started using Thread Pool ExecutorService or by any method at once?

Tags: java, multithreading, threadpool

I want to start all the threads from Thread Group at once.

```
    ThreadGroup1 obj = new ThreadGroup1();
    ThreadGroup tg1 = new ThreadGroup("Parent ThreadGroup");

    Thread t1=new Thread(tg1, obj, "one");
    Thread t2=new Thread(tg1, obj, "two");
    Thread t3=new Thread(tg1, obj, "three");

    t1.start();
    t2.start();
    t3.start();
```

Answer (score 0):

"At once" makes sense only in real time environment, and means "during given interval of time". The program you demonstrated starts all 3 threads during relatively small time interval for most cases, but sometimes, when the main thread is preempted, this interval can be significant. And even if the main thread executed uninterruptedly, the real moment of time when all the 3 threads starts actual execution my vary. First, does your machine has 3 physical processors to run the threads? If yes, are they free or are occupied by other processes? After your threads start, very soon they can be deprived from processor - is it as important for you as the moment they start? You see, there are too many variants how real execution can happen, and it is very hard to guarantee your threads start "at once" or finish in desirable time interval. You can run your program hundreds of times but this does not proof it will always work as desired.
So if you are seriously want to be sure your threads start "at once", learn ["Real time programming"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real-time_computing). And remember, real time programming is not how to make fast programs, but about how to make programs which are guaranteed to finish their work during given time interval.